# Packaging a LAMP application for easy deployment

Tags: php, linux, apache, deployment, lamp

I'm the resident "computer guy" for my mom's small business.  About a year ago I set up a spare Dell box as an Ubuntu server sitting on the LAN in the shop, set up a LAMP stack on it and built a few intranet web applications (mostly with PHP and MySQL) for things like managing customer rewards data, inventory, employee timelogs, etc.  I went on to implement a custom barcode-and-cooking-instructions label generator with a frontend to print on Avery templates, and a fully-fledged Cash Register frontend with barcode scanning, custom hooks for inventory management, and a suite of accounting reports.  My little database apps have become a part of the daily procedures and business model for the shop.

Recently my mom told me she has a potential franchisee who wants to license the business model and open up a sister store in another state, complete with my software.

Now, my code is nice and stable, I have extensive documentation for *using* it, but I'm not going to be available to help the new folks get it up and running.  To make matters worse, it's not just a simple LAMP stack with some files in the docroot, setup involves using custom Apache config files, setting up MySQL databases and users, and installing a few esoteric dependencies like ImageMagick and its PHP Imagick extension (which I had to compile from source!)

Is there any good way to make some kind of one-step install script or package that will install the dependencies I need, my custom apache configuration, and extract my PHP files all into place?  Something that I could present to someone who's never configured Apache before that would get it up and running without my help?  Perhaps even some way to easily get an image of the entire OS and stack that they can clone onto a new drive without expertise?

Sorry if this is subjective, but my google has failed me.

Comment: I think a nice install script will take care of it all :)

Comment: +1 for install script... There ain't a lot more to say. And BTW, if everything that the Application is dependent on is in the LAMP folder, you could put that big guy in compressed file and replace a fresh LAMP install with it. Works for me but I don't have a lot of differences.

Comment: That would be nice, but the biggest problem is that the label printing stuff all depends on imagemagick and imagick, which require some package management stuff and tweaks to php.ini, etc.  I'm trying to avoid the need for the client to hire an expert just to get it all configured.

Comment: Software should be installed using the software management. Do not bypass it. Using the systems native package management capabilities you can run scripts during installation if required. You can do everything you could when using an install script. But when using the package management system it is a clean install that can be removed again, can be upgraded in a clean way AND CAN BE SEEN BY SOMEONE ELSE MAINTAINING THE SYSTEM!

Comment: @arkascha that's exactly what I want!  I just don't know how.

Comment: Well, there are two wide spread package management families out there used in Linux distributions: rpm style and deb style. Both are documented, thousands of examples exist. You also might want to take a look at the `Open Build System` offered by the openSUSE distribution. It helps in generating and offering packages for many common distributions and is very convenient. But, true, you have to read into how package management works and how to generate a package. It is worth it!

Comment: Ok I'll do some research, thanks!  If you want to post your response as an answer, I'll vote you up.

Comment: And then there's also the possibility to ship a "complete" appliance, e.g. a live-usb stick or a virtual machine image. Even a pre-configured box would be possible for a franchise.

Comment: @VolkerK yeah, that's probably more along the lines of what I need.  I want to make it easy to set up even for someone who's never seen a command prompt before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just ship them a server with all the software installed and configured? You could either make it part of the franchise requirement OR you could set yourself up as a technology provider (and the franchise license requires them to use your software/hardware).

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like this option.  The downside though is it depends on my continued involvement, rather than having them just follow my instructions.

Comment: Well unless you plan on no longer supporting your mom you're going to be supporting the software anyway - might as well get paid by the franchisee(s) too :-) And in the future if you decide you don't want to do it anymore you can sell the business, just give them the source code, whatever.

Comment: Touché.  Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 3):

#### Did you check out [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/)?

> Server2Go is a Webserver that runs out of the box without any installation and on write protected media. This means that web applications based on Server2Go can be used directly from cdrom, a usb stick or from any folder on a hard disk without the hassle of configuring Apache, PHP or MySQL.
>
> Server2Go allows you to create a standalone working web site or PHP application on a CD-ROM. There are many examples of its possible useses such as catalogue software, calculation programmes, image campaigns (CMS-based), computer based training lessons or other applicatons. Most PHP-Software such as the content management system Joomla or the computer based training software Moodle can be used from CD-ROM with the help of Server2Go.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that!